# convergence, bounded sequences, and limits

Tags: limits, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

Just want to get this straight in my head, so when doing proofs, proving that a sequence is convergent and proving if it is bounded is pretty much doing the same thing.  They both use the same technique that being $|x_n-x|< \epsilon$ for all $n>M$.  Also find the limit is the same process correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Showing that a sequence converges and finding its limit is often the same thing. You find a guess for the limit $x$ of the sequence $x_n$, and then show that for any $\epsilon$, there is an $M$ such that if $n\geq M$, $|x_n-x|<\epsilon$.

But showing boundedness is different. To show boundedness, you have to find a number $D$ so that $|x_n|\leq D$ for all $n$. There are various ways to do this, but it is usually not the same as showing that a sequence converges because a sequence can be bounded without converging, for instance $x_n=(-1)^n$. A convergent sequence is always bounded though.